# EF4 & SQL Server 2014: Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4

My web application is using Entity Framework 4.0 and 2 Microsoft SQL Servers:

- test server (ver 11.0.9231 - SQL Server 2012)
- production server (ver 12.0.2548.0 - SQL Server 2014)

Test aplication works ok without errors, but on production machine this error appears:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while
>   executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into
>   smaller queries. at ...

Do I need install any patches for production SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need install any patches for production SQL server? Actually, what you need to do is upgrade/patch your test environment to the same version as production.

The real error is not that it failed in production but that it succeeded in test.  Even if you create a fix for the production issue, where can you test it since it only happens in prod?

What is the actual query generated by Entity Framework?  I suspect that when you look at the actual query you will be much closer to understanding the problem.  Your query is probably a monster that should be re-written even if it works in a "test" environment.